# Laravel test failing when looking for data at view table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-9, php-pest

I'm writing an integration/feature test in Laravel 9 (using Pest) in which I create an `Address` that's associated to an existing customer. My customers' data live under a view that is created via migration:

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        DB::statement($this->createCustomersView());
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement($this->dropCustomersView());
    }

    private function createCustomersView() : string
    {
        return "CREATE VIEW view_customers AS
                    SELECT * FROM (
                        SELECT id, 'individuals' AS customer_type,
                        identification, identification_type,
                        CONCAT(first_name, ' ', IFNULL(middle_name,''), ' ',
                        last_name, ' ', IFNULL(second_last_name,'')) AS name,
                        primary_phone_number, created_at
                        FROM individuals
                        UNION
                        SELECT id, 'businesses' AS customer_type,
                        identification, identification_type, name,
                        primary_phone_number, created_at
                        FROM businesses
                    ) AS customers
                ORDER BY created_at DESC";
    }

    private function dropCustomersView() : string
    {
        return "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_customers";
    }
};
```

There's a rule set for `Address` which indicates that a `Customer` must exists in the view table:

```
'customers_id' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                Rule::exists('view_customers', 'id'),
            ],
```

My test is the following:

```
function baseTestAddress(string $customerType="") : array
{
    if (empty($customerType)) {
        // randomly select one type
        $types = ['business', 'individual'];
        $customerType = $types[array_rand($types)];
    }

    $customer = $customerType == 'individual' ? Individual::factory()->create() : Business::factory()->create();

    return [
        "customers_id" => $customer->id,
        "address_line_1" => "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
        "address_line_2" => "",
        "city" => "Washington",
        "state" => "DC",
        "zipcode" => "20500",
        "country" => "US",
        "notes" => "",
        "phone_number_1" => "6464698383",
        "phone_number_1_type" => "cel",
        "phone_number_1_extension" => "",
        "phone_number_2" => "",
        "phone_number_2_type" => "",
        "phone_number_2_extension" => "",
        "active" => true
    ];
}

it('should create a new address record when all provided values are valid', function () {
    $address = baseTestAddress();
    $response = $this->postJson(ADDRESSES_URI, $address);
    
    expect($response->status())->toEqual(Response::HTTP_CREATED)
        ->and($response->json('data'))
        ->id->not->toBeNull()
        ->type->toBe(ADDRESSES_RESOURCE_TYPE)
        ->attributes->toBeArray()
        ->attributes->customers_id->toBe($address['customers_id'])
        ->attributes->address_line_1->toBe($address['address_line_1'])
        ->attributes->address_line_2->toBe($address['address_line_2'])
        ->attributes->zipcode->toBe($address['zipcode'])
        ->attributes->state->toBe($address['state'])
        ->attributes->country->toBe($address['country'])
        ->attributes->notes->toBe($address['notes'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_1->toBe($address['phone_number_1'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_1_type->toBe($address['phone_number_1_type'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_1_extension->toBe($address['phone_number_1_extension'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_2->toBe($address['phone_number_2'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_2_type->toBe($address['phone_number_2_type'])
        ->attributes->phone_number_2_extension->toBe($address['phone_number_2_extension'])
        ->attributes->active->toBeTrue();
})->only();
```

The test is currently failing, if I print the response I see the following error:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: CONCAT (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "view_customers" where "id" = 3339d86c-088d-4c3a-8484-79e4821657f6)",\n
> "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",

The migration for the view ran successfully, and the view works as expected. Don't exactly know where this error is coming from.
Using the same data from the test I'm able to successfully create an address from my REST client.

Comment: Just saw that SQLite (the one being used for Unit Tests) doesn't support Concat. My datastore is MySQL.

Comment: Use docker to create a local container and have PHP in one container and MySQL in another container both matching production versions